# Why does JS alert kill my registration form?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I just finished my first working registration form connected to a database. Actually, it's basically a copy of a tutorial demo @ http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/milk/ except I had to add the database stuff.

I still have one minor bug. The form doesn't work unless I delete this code:

```
// specifying a submitHandler prevents the default submit, good for the demo
submitHandler: function() {
alert("submitted!");
},
```

It's kind of trivial, but it would be nice if the user could see some sort of "Success" message when they click the Submit button. I didn't want to post all the code, but I have a live page @ http://www.govwa.org/test/registration.php

This is the PHP code that I inserted just before the form closing tag:

```
include('config.php');
$pdo = connect();

// adding new member using PDO with try/catch to escape the exceptions
try {
 $sql = "INSERT INTO g1_members (firstname, lastname, username,  password, password_confirm, email) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname,  :username, :password, :password_confirm, :email)";
  $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $query->bindParam(':firstname', $_POST['firstname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query->bindParam(':lastname', $_POST['lastname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query->bindParam(':password', $_POST['password'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query->bindParam(':password_confirm', $_POST['password_confirm'],  PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query->execute();
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'PDOException : '.  $e->getMessage();
 }
```

Does anyone have a hunch what the problem might be? Alternatively, is there another way of displaying a message when someone clicks the Submit button?

Comment: you haven't provided enough code for us to solve this, however, it's likely a race condition caused by you not canceling the default form submit.

Comment: It says right there "specifying a submitHandler prevents the default submit". You specified one, which prevents the default submit, hence it doesn't submit.

Answer (score 5):

The `submitHandler` replaces the default submit, so the form is never submitted when you add that handler, you have to do it manually.

From the documentation

> Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is valid. Gets
>   the form as the only argument. Replaces the default submit. The right
>   place to submit a form via Ajax after it is validated.

either remove it, or submit the form once valid in the handler

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    alert("submitted!");
    form.submit()
},
```